# How use certificate to call soap API in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, soap

I want to use a soap API to pull some data from a system. The API developer provided me two certificates and asked me to use them in my code. He said if I do not use them when I want to call the API I won’t get the full set of data. It is my first time that I want to use certificate to call a soap API and I do not have any Idea. I did some search on the internet but I could not find anything that can help me. 
Here is my application details:
1.  ASP.net
2.  C#
3.  .Net framework 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Making the assumption that this is an X509 Certificate, you would generate a reference to the CERT file, and then add it to the ClientCertificates property of the WebRequest object.

```
//You must change the path to point to your .cer file location. 
X509Certificate Cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("C:\\mycert.cer");
// Handle any certificate errors on the certificate from the server.
ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new CertPolicy();
// You must change the URL to point to your Web server.
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://YourServer/sample.asp");
Request.ClientCertificates.Add(Cert);
Request.UserAgent = "Client Cert Sample";
Request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
```

For more details, information go to: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/895971

Sometimes the CERT file is password protected. This is VB.Net code, but it generates the CERT object when there's a password on the file:

```
Dim fs As FileStream = File.Open(certfilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Dim buffer As Byte()
ReDim buffer(fs.Length)
Dim count As Integer = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
fs.Close()
Dim cert As X509Certificate2 = New X509Certificate2(buffer, passwordToFile)
```

Also note that if you're using SoapHttpClientProtocol (or inheriting it into a specific class to consume this SOAP API, as do the other System.Web.Protocol elements) that it also contains the ClientCertificates property.